# asp.net + Weird looking string appended to URL

Tags: asp.net, url

I am having weird looking strings like this:

```
http://localhost:10012/user.aspx#.UPpCfl54stU
```

appended to the back of my URL and it only happens when I click on Link A when I am in any other pages other then the page of Link A, if I am on the Link A page and click on Link A(Reload) it doesn't happen. Anyone knows what is this and how to get rid of it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This string is coming 99% from a Facebook plugin that you use on your site.

Facebook adds that string at the end, reads it from the javascript and do what he do, maybe keeps statistics, maybe something else.

Comment: OK thanks for the info, maybe is the comment plugin that I am using.